# Bash - How to terminate a script and run the next one

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i'm using cygwin on windows to exploit the vsftp 2.3.4 as a class project,I have an idea how to do that and I actually have my shell code as below (it's my first time working with it)

```
!/usr/bin/bash
command1="ncat -v "$1" 21"
echo `$command1`
echo `USER X:)\r\nPASS X\r\n`
command2="ncat -v "$1" 6200"
echo `$command2`
```

So pretty much I need to trigger the connection with user x:) then it will open the shell on the port 6200. If I manually type in terminal then after typing in "ncat -v ip 21 [enter] USER x:) [enter] PASS x [enter]", i can now exit the current shell script by using ctrl + C and then type in "ncat -v ip 6200" to start the exploit.

Problem is if I run the shell code above, it will hang after typing in "PASS x" and will not exit so the next chunk of code will not be executed. (unless I ctrl + C in the terminal and it will starts running again).

I would like that process of using Ctrl + C to be automatic, is it anyway that I can do that?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a here-doc to provide input to a command:

```
ncat -v "$1" 21 <<EOF
USER X:)
PASS X
EOF
ncat -v "$1" 6200
```

To run it in the background, put `&` after `<<EOF`:

```
ncat -v "$1" 21 <<EOF &
USER X:)
PASS X
EOF
```

Your script is hanging because `ncat` is reading from standard input, which is connected to the terminal, so it's waiting for you to type something. It doesn't go to the next command until `ncat` exits.

If you want to use `echo` to provide input to a command, you have to pipe it:

```
echo -e "USER X:)\r\nPASS X\r\n" | ncat -v "$1" 21
```

Comment: thanks, also I need to run that in the background before starting the next command, so my solution is echo -e "USER X:)\r\nPASS X\r\n" | ncat -v "$1" 21 & with the &

Comment: I've added how to do that with the here-doc to the answer.